# Node size on GKE kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, rancher

We run our cluster with two nodes of type standard 2: 7.5Gb and 2vCPU

are there any recommended minimum size for a cluster on GKE. I assume there is no real master as this is a managed "service"?

I'm struggling to deal with resource limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no recommended minimum size. However, pods have both [CPU and memory requests and limits.](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/)

Requests define how much free CPU/memory there must be on a node so a pod can be scheduled there; that amount is then reserved for that pod and won't be considered 'free' for scheduling of a next pod.
On the other hand, limits define the maximum amount a pod can ask for - these can be overcommitted.

Try looking at your `kubectl describe nodes` output, which lists all pods and their requests and limits. By default, the requests are 100m (10% of a core) - if you know that some of your pods don't need that much, set this lower. Then you will be able to schedule more pods on a node or at least work out the number of nodes you need.

Comment: Follow on Q: my deployments get stuck as new pods coming in compete with resources of the ones going out... seems odd that I can't over commit during a deployment

Comment: Also is it better to have 2 larger nodes or 3 smaller nodes?