# How much RAM can my Kubernetes pod grow to?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to know the current limit on the RAM. (No limit/request was explicitly configured.)

How do I see the current configuration of an existing pod?

[Edit] That configuration would include not only how much memory is now in use, but also the  max-limit, the point at which it would be shut down.

(If I  blow up the heap with huge strings, I see a limit of approx 4 GB, and the Google Cloud Console shows a crash at 5.4 GB (which of course includes more than the Python interpreter), but I don't know where  this comes from. The Nodes have up to 10 GB.)

I tried `kubectl get pod id-for-the-pod -o yaml`, but it shows nothing about memory.

I am using Google Container Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment from @Artem Timchenko: `kubectl -n NAMESPACE describe pod POD_NAME | grep -A 2 "Limits"`

Comment: @Artem Timchenko if you can add an answer I can 'accept' that (and give you the credit for the answer)

Answer (score 5):

Use kubectl top command

`kubectl top pod id-for-the-pod`

> **kubectl top** --help
>
> Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage.
>
> The top command allows you to see the resource consumption for nodes
> or pods.
>
> This command requires Heapster to be correctly configured and working
> on the server.
>
> Available Commands:   node        Display Resource
> (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of nodes   pod         Display Resource
> (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of pods
>
> Usage:   kubectl top [flags] [options]

Comment: Thank you. That shows 92Mi. I know that the memory can go much higher, even above 3Gi. How do I see the max-limit, the point at which it would be shutdown?

Answer (score 4):

The edit in the question asks how to see the max memory limit for an existing pod. This shold do:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod-name> cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes
```

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt

With QoS class of [BestEffort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#create-a-pod-that-gets-assigned-a-qos-class-of-besteffort) (seen in the output from `kubectl -n <namespace> get pod <pod-name> -o yaml` or `kubectl -n <namespace> describe pod <pod-name>`), there may be no limits (other than the available memory on the node where the pod is running) so the value returned can be a large number (e.g. 9223372036854771712 - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420906/what-is-the-value-for-the-cgroups-limit-in-bytes-if-the-memory-is-not-restricte) for an explanation).

Comment: The first kubectl command gives Your kibectl  9223372036854771712 , which of course just means "undefined'.

Comment: Right - the command allows one to determine the limit or that there isn't a limit set. With no limits set, QoS class is BestEffort and the available memory on the node on which the pod is running will determine when the pod will run out of memory. I'd suggest https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/ and to take a look at the script referenced on that doc page - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/memory-available.sh . HTH

Answer (score 3):

You can use

> kubectl top pod POD_NAME

It will show you memory and CPU usage.

[Edit: See comment for more]

Comment: Thank you. That shows 92Mi. I know that the memory can go much higher, even above 3Gi. How do I see the max-limit, the point at which it would be shutdown?

Comment: @JoshuaFox from kubernetes side this is handled like described in official documentation:

`If a Container exceeds its memory limit, it might be terminated. If it is restartable, the kubelet will restart it, as with any other type of runtime failure.`

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Limit is described by spec.containers[].resources.limits.memory

Comment: The easiest way to see those limits is to use something like this:
`kubectl -n NAMESPACE describe pod POD_NAME | grep -A 2 "Limits"`

Comment: please add this as an answer so I can "Accept" it.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by the community, you can run "kubectl top pod POD_NAME" to get how much memory your pod is using. The max limit actually depends on the available memory of nodes (You may get an idea of CPU Requests and CPU Limits of nodes by running "kubectl describe nodes"). Furthermore, the max limit of the pod also depends on its [memory requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) as defined in the pod's configuration ("requests" and "limits" specs under "resources"). You can also read this relevant [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910362/node-size-on-gke-kubernetes).

Comment: Thank you. But in this case, the pod has no requests and limits configured in the yaml. (But the rest of your answer is qyite useful)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) in Kubernetes Cluster (Heapster is deprecated) and then use

> kubectl top POD_NAME

to get pod CPU and memory usages.